# How do you pass site.data to includes within includes in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a snippet of code I include whenever I need to display a gallery.

```
<!-- _includes/gallery.md -->

{% assign items = {{include.data}} %}
{% for item in items -%}
{% assign src = item.path | prepend: "/assets/images/" | relative_url %}
[![{{item.alt}}]({{src}}){:.gallery-{{items.size}}}]({{src}})
{%- endfor %}
{:.text-center}
```

I can pass `site.data` to populate the gallery.

```
{% include gallery.md data = site.data.index.themes %}
```

I have a template page which needs to display a gallery. I want to pass in `site.data` as well.

```
<!-- _includes/create-new.md -->

Create a new {{include.type}}:

{% include gallery.md data = {{include.site_data}} %}
```

But when I try to pass in `site.data` to the template page, I get an error.

```
{% include create-new.md type = "layout" site_data = site.data.index.layouts %}
```

How do you pass `site.data` to includes within includes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass it like any other data irrespective of whether nested within another include tag:

```
<!-- _includes/create-new.md -->

Create a new {{ include.type }}:

{% include gallery.md data = include.site_data %}
```

Comment: I see, so the `{{...}}` is bascially `.toString()`

Comment: Not exactly. `{{ ... }}` is for interpolation akin to using backticks in JS. But the semantic is slightly different for Jekyll's `include` tag. The `{{ ... }}` is only applicable as interpolation for the filename (say, `galley.md` was actually assigned to a variable). For parameters, interpolation is implied, if the values are not quoted.